# Replace NA with minimum Group Value R

Tags: r

I'm struggeling with transforming my data and would appreciate some help

| year | name | start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2011 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2012 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2009 | John | na |
| 2010 | John | na |
| 2012 | John | na |
| 2007 | Louis | na |
| 2012 | Louis | na |

the aim is to replace all NAs with the minimum value in year for every name group so the data looks like this

| year | name | start |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2010 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2011 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2012 | Emma | 1998 |
| 2009 | John | 2009 |
| 2010 | John | 2009 |
| 2012 | John | 2009 |
| 2007 | Louis | 2007 |
| 2012 | Louis | 2007 |

Note: either all start values of one name group are NAs or none

I tried to use

```
mydf %>%   group_by(name) %>%   mutate(start= ifelse(is.na(start), min(year, na.rm = T), start))
```

but got this error

```
x `start` must return compatible vectors across groups
```

There are a lot of similar problems here.
Some people here used the ave function or worked with data.table which both doesnt seem to fit my problem

My base function must be sth like

```
df$A <- ifelse(is.na(df$A), df$B, df$A)
```

however I cant seem to properly combine it with the min() and group by() function.

Thank you for any help

Comment: `mydf %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(start= ifelse(is.na(start), min(year, na.rm = T), start))` works for me. Please provide data in a reproducible format using `dput`. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the colname to 'Year' because it was colliding to

```
dat %>% 
    dplyr::group_by(name) %>% 
    dplyr::mutate(start = dplyr::if_else(start == "na", min(Year), start))
```

```
# A tibble: 8 x 3
# Groups:   name [3]
  Year  name  start
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 2010  Emma  1998 
2 2011  Emma  1998 
3 2012  Emma  1998 
4 2009  John  2009 
5 2010  John  2009 
6 2012  John  2009 
7 2007  Louis 2007 
8 2012  Louis 2007
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `na.aggregate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
dat %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(start = na.aggregate(na_if(start, "na"), FUN = min))
```